# How to add Bundle Identifier correctly to my app in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have created App ID Prefix and Bundle ID in AppStore and I am wondering if that together forms the bundle identifier like so:

```
[AppIDPrefix].[com.myapp.extension]
```

Furthermore, when I add it like that in XCode -> Target app -> General -> Bundle Identifier, it automatically adds a dash (-) before the identifier. Why?

FYI App ID Prefix looks something like this: **8HJ23V44G5**

Also, I am not sure if **SKU** should be added anywhere in XCode or not. Please let me know.